# Youtube unauthorized error when uploading videos through api

Tags: youtube-api

I am using a javascript uploader to upload videos to Youtube. To make API requests I am using an OAuth2.0 access token. This uploader works fine. But once in months it starts to give error Unauthorized by Youtube API. To resolve this issue I have to go to https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha and click continue then the uploader starts to work again.

I have read about CAPTCHA verification in Youtube API documentation but isn't it just for ClientLogin for installed apps that do not use OAuth2.0 access token?

Also is there a way to permanently off CAPTCHA verification as even I implement some logic in my uploader to handle CAPTCHA verification I will not be able to test it again until it starts to give me error again.

Note: Most of the times video is uploaded 100% and sometimes less than 100% when it gives error. Shouldn't it give error on the first request to API when we are just sending metadata of the video?